# Can't understand why there is a syntax error - laravel syntax error

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I haven't changed anything to the 1st route. I only added the form submission routes then the error occurred, yet it's pointing to the first route?

The error points to line 17 with the following, yet I can't understand why.

`syntax error, unexpected token "::", expecting "," or ";"`

```
17> Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('welcome');
    });


// AiFx - This route allows the guests to view the page - //
Route::get('/guests', function () {
    return view('guests');
});

// AiFx - This route allows the completed form to be submitted to DB - this one didnt populate the DB!!??- //
Route::post('/guests', function () {
    $GuestController::create([
        'fname' => request.query->get('fname'),
        'lname' => request.query->get('lname'),
        'id_number' => request.query->get('id_number'),
        'mobile' => request.query->get('mobile'),
        'sqsymptoms' => request.query->get('sqsymptoms'),
        'sqtravel' => request.query->get('sqtravel'),
        'sqcontact' => request.query->get('sqcontact'),
    ])
    public function getRouteKey() {
        return $this->submit;
    }
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Comment: i added my `model App\Model\Guest;` which removed the error.. but its now pointing to the `    public function getRouteKey() {
        return $this->submit;
    }`   did i get this wrong?

Comment: That syntax error often means the statement before it didn’t finish properly, such as a missing semicolon. In the third route above (the post one) there appears to be one missing, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing semicolon.

```
$GuestController::create([
    'fname' => request.query->get('fname'),
    'lname' => request.query->get('lname'),
    'id_number' => request.query->get('id_number'),
    'mobile' => request.query->get('mobile'),
    'sqsymptoms' => request.query->get('sqsymptoms'),
    'sqtravel' => request.query->get('sqtravel'),
    'sqcontact' => request.query->get('sqcontact'),
]);
```

Also,

```
public function getRouteKey() {
    return $this->submit;
}
```

Is not working within the route, its a function to Override the Route Key name within a model when using Route Model Binding. I dont know what you are trying to achieve, but im pretty sure it does nothing for you here.
[Check Docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects)